# Process RAM Usage in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, memory-management

Guys, I am using *[GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219%28VS.85%29.aspx)* function to get the details of a current process in Visual Studio 2008 running on Windows 7. The output is populated in [PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684877%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure with a list of following members.

- cb
- PageFaultCount
- PeakWorkingSetSize
- WorkingSetSize
- QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage
- QuotaPagedPoolUsage
- QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage
- QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage
- PagefileUsage
- PeakPagefileUsage

Which one of these members should I use to get the RAM usage of the process? 
Is there another way to get the memory usage of a process using Microsoft Visual C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WorkingSetSize` to retrieve physical RAM usage per process.  Per the [MSDN docs for the underlying Win32 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683226%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> The "working set" of a process is the
>   set of memory pages currently visible
>   to the process in physical RAM memory.
>   These pages are resident and available
>   for an application to use without
>   triggering a page fault.

There is no other way to get the current working set size than what you are using.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684891%28VS.85%29.aspx) for details.